# m2e pick up sources from ${sourceDirectory}/main/java

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I set `<sourceDirectory>target/src</sourceDirectory>` in my pom, because i use some custom ant `process-sources` steps. Maven compile project well, it automaticaly search sources in `target/src/main/java`, but eclipse try to pick it up exactly from `target/src`, assuming `main/java` is a java packet. If i manually add sources dir `target/src/main/java` in eclipse project settings, then `update maven project` won't work. How to setup m2e to work in maven-way and pickup sources from `${sourceDirectory}/main/java`?

Answer (score 0):

M2E plugin always parses the pom.xml and sets the preferences in the eclipse accordingly. It is better to change source directory as

```
<sourceDirectory> target/src/main/java </sourceDirectory>
```

or try using profiles in your pom. Refer http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html